# API can't call initSession it shows 404 page

Tags: php, api, nginx

Why I can't call the InitSession?

Explanation:

```
.../apirest.php ==> leads to documentation
```

request:

```
$ curl -X GET \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H "Authorization: user_token xxx" \
-H "App-Token: xxx" \
.../apirest.php/initSession
```

Result

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

on GLPI
URL of the API: localhost/api
Enable Rest API: Yes
API client has been added
```

What is missing?

specs:

```
version GLPI 9.1.1
server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.26
```

the config:

```
server {
    listen 8001;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /home/locadirectory;
   
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #       proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
    #}

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location /api {
            rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /apirest.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #       # With php5-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php5-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

localhost/api is not a correct API URL.
It should be something like http://localhost/apirest.php

Said that 9.1 is pretty old and the first GLPI API release.
Current stable is 9.5, and I can tell you 9.4 and up will have a lot more features both the software itself and its API.